# Creat and send SVG by telegram bot

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, telegram-bot

I need creat seats map and send it by telegram bot(node.js)
I have JSON with cordinates like this

```
            "hallid": "200",
            "hallName": "Hall 3",
            "width": 561,
            "height": 499,
            "widthScreen": 1024,
            "heightScreen": 768,
            "horizontalRatio": 2,
            "verticalRatio": 2,
            "seats": [
                {
                    "x": 144,
                    "y": 288,
                    "width": 21,
                    "height": 57,
                    "id": "D00001",
                    "row": "D",
                    "seat": "1",
                    "idSector": "000000308",
                    "idTypeOfSeat": "001"
                },
     {
                    "x": 320,
                    "y": 288,
                    "width": 21,
                    "height": 57,
                    "id": "D00007",
                    "row": "D",
                    "seat": "7",
                    "idSector": "000000308",
                    "idTypeOfSeat": "001"
                }...

            ]
        },
```

I've try do it like in frontend, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The Telegram client can't display SVG images. If you want the image to be visible in the client, convert it to a supported format: JPEG, PNG, or WebM.